# Python Itertools: Complex "product"

Tags: python, product, python-itertools

```
1+3+9 = 13 = 1+3 = 4.
6+1+1+5 = 13 = 1+3 = 4.
9+9+4 = 22 = 2+2 = 4.
etc
```

Considering the previous examples, one could say that the possibilities of reduction to the number 4 goes up to infinity. Nevertheless, IT IS possible to control the number of digits that enters in the initial game of sums.

```
def reduct(length):
    ...
    ...
    return reduction
```

Do you guys have any Idea of how I could code a function like this? I want to input a "length", and, supposing it to be 7 for example, and supposing that the ending reduction is 5, I want it to do this:

x+x+x+x+x+x+x = 5.

Where it gives me ALL THE POSSIBILITIES for the x numbers.

I've spent too much time trying to solve the problem and I could not  figure out how to do it. It's  a very nice programming exercise by the way (A good challenge); I thank you all very much for the help.

Comment: what is the limit of the length? You want all the solution or just the count?

Comment: The length will be specified by a "raw_input". It could be any number. So, I would like to know how the function would be with any length, just to see how it would work :).

Comment: are you saying there is no limit on the length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to conjure up a solution (assuming `itertools` has already been imported):

```
def reduct(length, n=5):
    return [i for i in \
            itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 10), length) \
            if ((sum(i) - 1) % 9 + 1) == n]
```

This returns all unique combinations that "reduce" to `n`, which is `5` by default.

---

Explanation:

- `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 10), length)` yields all unique combinations of `length` one digit numbers (excluding `0`). See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).
- `((sum(i) - 1) % 9 + 1)` yields the "reduction" of each combination. It uses the [digital root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) formula `((n - 1) % 9 + 1`, with `n` as the sum of the numbers in the combination.
- The rest is self explanatory (I hope).

---

Some test runs:

```
>>> reduct(2)
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (5, 9), (6, 8), (7, 7)]
>>> reduct(3)
[(1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 4, 9), (1, 5, 8), (1, 6, 7), (2, 3, 9),
 (2, 4, 8), (2, 5, 7), (2, 6, 6), (3, 3, 8), (3, 4, 7), (3, 5, 6),
 (4, 4, 6), (4, 5, 5), (5, 9, 9), (6, 8, 9), (7, 7, 9), (7, 8, 8)]
>>> len(reduct(7))
715
```

Specifying a custom `n`:

```
>>> reduct(2, 8)
[(1, 7), (2, 6), (3, 5), (4, 4), (8, 9)]
>>> reduct(3, 8)
[(1, 1, 6), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 7, 9), (1, 8, 8), (2, 2, 4),
 (2, 3, 3), (2, 6, 9), (2, 7, 8), (3, 5, 9), (3, 6, 8), (3, 7, 7),
 (4, 4, 9), (4, 5, 8), (4, 6, 7), (5, 5, 7), (5, 6, 6), (8, 9, 9)]
>>> len(reduct(7, 8))
715
```

Comment: @EricsonWillians no worries. It was an interesting challenge!

Comment: @wim yeah. I didn't actually know about it until I read it on another SO post (can't find it now, unfortunately). It's pretty nifty.